# Ошибка по адресу

Tags: c++, c++builder

Помогите найти ошибку... Программа компилится, запускается. Но при нажатии на кнопку... Вылетает ошибка по адресу.

*View -> Debug Windows -> Call Stack*.

```
00401BE9 Morf(S1={ "111" }, T=false)
```

`B = S1[I];` <- ругается на это. Почему не знаю... С C++ не очень сильно знаком.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AnsiString Morf(AnsiString S1, bool T)
{
    int LS;
    int KB;
    int B;
    int W;
    AnsiString S2;

    LS = S1.Length();
    KB = LS * LS;
    if (!T)
    {
        for (int I = 0; I < LS; I++)
        {
            B = S1[I];
            if (B > 32)
            {
                W = B + KB;
                if (W > 255)
                    W = W - 223;
                B = W;
            }; // If
            S2 += static_cast<char>(B);
            KB = (KB + (I * 2)) & 127;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int I = 0; I < LS; I++)
        {
            B = S1[I];
            if (B > 32)
            {
                W = B - KB;
                if (W < 33)
                    W = W + 223;
                B = W;
            }
            S2 += static_cast<char>(B);
            KB = (KB + (I * 2)) & 127;
        }
    }
    return S2;
}




void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
Edit2->Text = Morf(Edit1->Text, false);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
//Edit4->Text = Morf(Edit3->Text, true);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Стек вызовов в момент падения:

```
7565B727 C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
40005B68 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rtl60.bpl
77436A8B ntdll.dll
77400143 ntdll.dll
0040276A System::AnsiString::ThrowIfOutOfRange
00401DA7 System::AnsiString::operator [](this=:0018F280, idx=0)
00401BE9 Morf(S1={ "123" }, T=false)
00401E2B TForm1::Button1Click(this=:00A15688, Sender=:00A173C0)
4010798A C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcl60.bpl
4010A9A8 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcl60.bpl
4010AAE0 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcl60.bpl
4010A9A8 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcl60.bpl
4010A623 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcl60.bpl
40037EEA C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rtl60.bpl
75DA62FA C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
75DA6D3A C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
75DB0D27 C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
75DB0D4D C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
72A2A7C2 C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\comctl32.dll
72A2A9D0 C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\comctl32.dll
72A2A985 C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\comctl32.dll
72A41BD0 C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\comctl32.dll
72A2A9D0 C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\comctl32.dll
72A2A8C3 C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\comctl32.dll
75DA62FA C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
75DA6D3A C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
75DA965E C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
75DA96C5 C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
75DE5FBB C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
75DE60FC C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
75DD312E C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
75DCAA3F C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
75DA62FA C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
75DA6D3A C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
75DB0D27 C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
75DB794A C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
4010AA8C C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcl60.bpl
4010A9A8 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcl60.bpl
40037EEA C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rtl60.bpl
75DA62FA C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
75DA6D3A C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
75DA77C4 C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
75DA7BCA C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll
400F5834 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcl60.bpl
004017AB WinMain( =:00400000,  =NULL,  =:007744E9,  =9)
3267E52F C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CC3260MT.DLL
```

Вот весь call stack. Может я что то не подключил...

Comment: Добавьте весь call-stack, сама ф-ия Morf вроде бы работает без ошибок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В AnsiString элементы считаются с 1, а не с 0. 
[Документация](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__AnsiString__[]@int.html)